# Maui Hybrid (.NET 8.0) how to persist the page state when switching the pages?

Tags: blazor, maui, maui-blazor

[asp.net core](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/discussions/52242)

As the above link, I create the question in the discussion of ASP.NET Core.

[image]

The Blazor page can not keep the state when I come back from another page. The experience that this brings to users is very bad, especially on the app. So I want to know how to keep the previous state?

Comment: `builder.Services.AddSingleton<YourPage>()` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-8.0

Comment: That's not the solution.  if we browse website with chrome/edge , when we go back , the previous page will restore. you can try it.

Comment: It does work. Check out Blazor Dependency Injection. You can watch a YouTube video on the subject: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G910vWOdhQ8

Comment: @StephenQuan We can use singleton service to keep some global data between the pages.  But should not use it in this scene. Despite I test  AddSingileton<Home> in a solution, it's not working.

Comment: I've used the dependency injection and it works fine and I've switched between transient to singleton and have seen my objects, particularly view models become singleton and persist during page transitions. Other people have made it work, so, I'm sure you should be able to. It's not clear if you are separating your view model from your page, you only mention pages in your example, perhaps that's the missing link?

Comment: I have added the pages as singleton, but it is still instantiated in every accessed. I create a demo repository: https://github.com/monster-echo/BlazorSingletonPageDemo.git. Can you take a look at it for me, thanks.  And I work on dotnet core 8.0

Comment: @StephenQuan Could show a demo like this? I think this is an inescapable topic if we make a app with blazor. But I can not search some topics about it. So maybe I'm taking the wrong way

Comment: Created Pull Request for you to review: https://github.com/monster-echo/BlazorSingletonPageDemo/pull/1

Comment: @Echo-- imagine asking a question in a forum where there are quite a lot of real experts, but proceeding to act like you know everything.  You should do a tutorial series, as what you are asking is trivial to do.  Start here: https://blazor-university.com/

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 I'm sorry, I'm not trying to act like an expert.  I just want to describe my question clearly. Maybe my small vocabulary makes you misunderstand me, sincere apologies.

Comment: @StephenQuan I'm sorry, I really just want to describe the problem clearly.  Thank you for your patient advice

Comment: If English isn't your first language, then use Google's translate feature for blazor-university.com

Comment: Some days passed, I have made it clear what I want, it's not Singleton Dependency.  It's  NavigativePage or other alternatives. When we click the Counter Page or Weather Page, it should be popuped above the home page.

Comment: Very sorry to waste your time, I did not make clear the question when I started this thread. thanks, especial Stephen

Answer (score 1):

A quick hack would be to change `counter` to static, i.e.

```
private static int currentCount = 0;
```

But, a more robust way would be to declare a singleton service, say, `CounterService`, and register for dependency injection:

```cpp
// Components/Services/CounterService.cs
namespace blazorTest.Components.Services
{
    public class CounterService
    {
        public int Counter { get; set; } = 0;
    }
}
```

```cs
// Program.cs
using blazorTest.Components.Services;
// ...
builder.Services.AddSingleton<CounterService>();
```

```
// Counter.razor
@page "/counter"
@rendermode InteractiveServer
@inject Services.CounterService CounterService

<PageTitle>Counter</PageTitle>

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p role="status">Current count: @CounterService.Counter</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@code {
    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        CounterService.Counter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: I know the singleton service function. But when I go back to Weather page the page is refreshing and the scroll position is on the top.

Comment: When we play on a app like X (Twitter), we can enter a detail page of a thread, but when we click the back button, the main page is still there, and not refresh

Comment: Sorry, If you feel offended, I want you to apologize sincerely.   I'm having trouble describing multiple pages that I want like an Android app

Comment: Sorry, I cannot work full time on your issue. The dependency injection singleton shows how you can persist a value. In this case Counter. If there's other things you want to persist, then, you will also need to add it to your view model service.